# Как прибавить дни к числу? 28.11.2018 + 30 = 28.12.2018

Tags: php, веб-программирование

В общем есть дата, Не текущая, Как пример возьмём $EKDate = 28.11.2018;
Мне нужно прибавить к $EKDate 30 дней. 30 как число дней а не как дата.
Чтобы в итоге получилось 28.12.2018?

Comment: `Date` или time2string в помощь вам

Comment: Мне бы пример у меня сейчас вообще котелок не варит.
Я же не зря дал вам примеры своего кода.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', '28.11.2018');
$date->modify('+30 days');
echo $date->format('d.m.Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам пример, как это делаю я.

```
//ищем разницу в днях между началом и концом
    $daydata = daydiff($datastart, $dataend);
    //Просчитываем дни для периодов
    $firstperiod = intval($daydata*0.75);
    //полученные проценты прибавляем к начальной дате, и далее рассчитываем периоды
    $makedate1 = strtotime($datastart);
    $makedate1 = strtotime('+'.$firstperiod.' day', $makedate1);
    $makedate1 = date('Y-m-d', $makedate1);
```

Получаем интервал в днях, считаем число, от него берем 75%, потом в $makedate1 записываем  первую дату, затем прибавляем к ним получившееся число, затем приводим это к формату даты.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date('d.m.o', strtotime("$EKDate + 30 days"));
```